# Problems plotting ImplicitRegion

Tags: plotting, regions, implicit

I have run into some rather strange behavior regarding plotting over regions defined by `ImplicitRegion`. I have a condition given by

```
cond = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[2 a])^2 (-1803 + 7732 q^2 + 5744 q^4 + 5568 q^6 + 12 (33 + 644 q^2 + 816 q^4 + 704 q^6) Cos[a] + 4 (35 + 16 q^2 (4 + 79 q^2 + 56 q^4)) Cos[2 a] + 12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + (-1 + 4 q^2)^3 Cos[4 a]) Sin[a]^2
```

I define an region with

```
region = ImplicitRegion[{cond>0 && 0<q<0.5 && 0<a<Pi},{q,a}];
```

As an example, when I then call

```
ContourPlot[q*a, Element[{q, a}, region]]
```

I get the following output, which works great.

[image: successful contour plot]

However, for one particular case I need to define a slightly different region.

```
region2 = ImplicitRegion[{cond>0.1 && 0<q<0.5 && 0<a<Pi},{q,a}];
```

However, now the region is completely useless. It will not produce anything with `RegionPlot` and when `ContourPlot` is called it just returns the following:

[image: bad call]

Has anyone had any experience with this kind of behavior?

Comment: `stabRegion` is blue in your screenshot, indicating that it doesn't have a value assigned. Are you sure you evaluated all definitions, and that you are using the correct variable name?

Comment: Yes - this is just a screenshot from a few days after. I did not want to rerun it as it took ~20 minutes to return nothing.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[q*a, Element[{q, a}, DiscretizeRegion@reg]]`

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

We can directly use `RegionFunction`

```
cond = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 
      12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[
        2 a])^2 (-1803 + 7732 q^2 + 5744 q^4 + 5568 q^6 + 
     12 (33 + 644 q^2 + 816 q^4 + 704 q^6) Cos[a] + 
     4 (35 + 16 q^2 (4 + 79 q^2 + 56 q^4)) Cos[2 a] + 
     12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + (-1 + 4 q^2)^3 Cos[
       4 a]) Sin[a]^2;
ContourPlot[q*a, {q, 0, 0.5}, {a, 0, Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{q, a}, 
   cond > 0.1 && 0 < q < 0.5 && 0 < a < Pi // Evaluate], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Or

```
cond = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 
      12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[
        2 a])^2 (-1803 + 7732 q^2 + 5744 q^4 + 5568 q^6 + 
     12 (33 + 644 q^2 + 816 q^4 + 704 q^6) Cos[a] + 
     4 (35 + 16 q^2 (4 + 79 q^2 + 56 q^4)) Cos[2 a] + 
     12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + (-1 + 4 q^2)^3 Cos[
       4 a]) Sin[a]^2;
region2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{cond > 0.1 && 0 < q < 0.5 && 0 < a < Pi}, {q, a}];
ContourPlot[q*a, {q, 0, .5}, {a, 0, Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{q, a}, {q, a} ∈ region2]]
```

**Original**

We can use `DiscretizeRegion`

```
cond = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 
      12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[
        2 a])^2 (-1803 + 7732 q^2 + 5744 q^4 + 5568 q^6 + 
     12 (33 + 644 q^2 + 816 q^4 + 704 q^6) Cos[a] + 
     4 (35 + 16 q^2 (4 + 79 q^2 + 56 q^4)) Cos[2 a] + 
     12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + (-1 + 4 q^2)^3 Cos[
       4 a]) Sin[a]^2;
region2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{cond > 0.1 && 0 < q < 0.5 && 0 < a < Pi}, {q, a}];
disretegion2 = DiscretizeRegion[region2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
ContourPlot[q*a, Element[{q, a}, disretegion2]]
```

[image]

If we set `cond > 1000`, then we get
[image]